# Understanding C++ make shared pointer with const arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, smart-pointers

I found somewhere this piece of code:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const Foo> pFoo = boost::make_shared<const Foo>();
```

What's the aim of the `const` keyword here?

Comment: Isn't the same as the `const` in `const Foo *`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its very simple, it really is just a pointer pointing to a `const` Foo. The code, currently, which is:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const Foo> pFoo = boost::make_shared<const Foo>();
```

Is the basic equivalent of

```
const Foo * pFoo
```

The meaning of `const` here is regular as with `const` pointers
The advantage of this is that the pointer is read-only, because of `const`ness

Answer (score 2):

It creates a shared `const Foo` - that is, `const` has its regular meaning.

Comment: Does ot mean that I cannot change the content of Foo?

Comment: @lucab0ni No, you can't  modify `*pFoo`.

Answer (score 2):

`shared_ptr<const Foo> ptr` is similar to `const Foo * ptr`. So it's a pointer to const Foo

Answer (score 2):

std::shared_ptr \< const T> allows you just to read from pointed address in memory